# Connecting to Redis on Vagrant machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, vagrant

I'm trying to resolve this error when connecting from a Rails server to a Redis server, both running in Vagrant VM:

```
Redis::CannotConnectError: Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
```

I can verify the Redis server is running, I think, with the following:

```
ps aux | grep redis
redis      839  0.1  0.1  35140  1840 ?        Ssl  00:21   0:00 /usr/local/bin/redis-server *:6379 
vagrant   1220  0.0  0.0  11676   952 pts/0    R+   00:22   0:00 grep --color=auto redis

sudo netstat -tnlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6379            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      839/redis-server *:
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:57102           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      778/rpc.statd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      507/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      725/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::6379                 :::*                    LISTEN      839/redis-server *:
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      507/rpcbind
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      725/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::49667                :::*                    LISTEN      778/rpc.statd
```

I have this in my redis.conf:

```
# Accept connections on the specified port, default is 6379.
# If port 0 is specified Redis will not listen on a TCP socket.
port 6379

# If you want you can bind a single interface, if the bind option is not
# specified all the interfaces will listen for incoming connections.
#
bind 127.0.0.1
```

and Vagrantfile:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu-12.04-amd64"

  # THE URL FROM WHERE THE 'CONFIG.VM.BOX' BOX WILL BE FETCHED IF IT
  # DOESN'T ALREADY EXIST ON THE USER'S SYSTEM.
  config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box"

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 6379, host: 6379, auto_correct: true

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
  end

  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "init.sh"
end
```

I tried following the [canonical entry](https://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message) but am not making any headway.  It might be something obvious I'm overlooking.  Can someone point me in the right direction as to what else I can try?

EDIT: Full error message:

```
$redis = Redis.new(:host => '127.0.0.1', :port => 6379)
=> #<Redis client v3.2.2 for redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0>
$redis.set('a', 'b')
Redis::CannotConnectError: Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
```

EDIT: commented out the bind 127.0.0.1 and was able to ping from the redis box but still no luck from Rails:

```
redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 ping
PONG
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out, I needed to use the IP address of the adapter for my VM (VirtualBox) to get it to work on my Windows machine.  This worked:

```
$redis = Redis.new(:host => '192.168.56.1', :port => 6379)
=> #<Redis client v3.2.2 for redis://192.168.56.1:6379/0>
$redis.set('a', 'b')
=> "OK"
$redis.get('a')
=> "b"
```

Comment: Hello, how did you fund the ip address for your VM?

Comment: @MareksNo I believe that 192.168.56.1 is the default address for VirtualBox.  I think there is a way to change this, but I am not a networking expert.  You might search for that IP address on ServerFault for further insights.

Comment: Hmm ok, my server wasnt running because in layers config my dumbass decided to put the vagrants 10.0.0.2 as the host ip